# How to maintain both admin and user with devise gem?(Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using rails 4 with devise gem and following this article -"https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role", I created a model for admin also. Now I have both admin and user model. How can I get the current_admin as in application_helper, these are present:-

```
def resource_name
 :user
end

def resource
 @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
 @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

Please help to main a admin session. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise's current_X helper methods are defined like this:

```
def current_#{mapping}
        @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
      end
```

where mapping is the role type. *

As such, you should be able to access the current admin using:

```
current_admin
```

If this doesn't work, I would recommend checking to make sure that devise has been properly instanciated on the Admin model, as follows:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable # additional attributes, i.e. :trackable, :lockable 
end
```

*Source: Line 106 of https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb

---

If you continue to experience issues with this, it might be worth reconsidering whether you *need* to separate administrators and users using different models, instead of simplifying both the model and the implementation by adding an administrative attribute to the users model.

---

**Edit:**

To give you an idea as to how much of a negligible performance difference there would be querying a single users table for administrative users vs having two tables, I seeded a MySQL database (running on XAMPP for OSX, so it is by no means heavily optimized) with 1000 user records, with only 2 of the users having 'isAdmin' set to true.
Query using SQL (Selecting Admins from a pool of 1000 Users):

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE isAdmin = 1
```

Result:

```
Showing rows 0 - 1 (2 total, Query took 0.0004 seconds.)
```

Query using SQL (Selecting Admins from an Admin table):

```
SELECT * FROM `administrators`
```

Result:

```
Showing rows 0 - 16 (17 total, Query took 0.0003 seconds.)
```

This is by no means an incredibly thorough example - it was just to provide an idea as to the minimal difference when used like this. Active Record may be slightly quicker/slower, but I can't imagine it would be too different to the results above.

Personally, I find it easier to add an 'isAdmin' (or similar) attribute to my users model, like this:

**Active Record migration (db\migrate\TIMESTAMP_create_users.rb)**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
       t.string :username
       t.boolean :isAdmin, default: false
        ...
    end
  end
end
```

and then filter between Users and Administrators like so:
**Users, except Admins**

```
users = User.where(:isAdmin => false)
```

**All users**

```
allUsers = User.all
```

**Admins only**

```
admins = User.where(:isAdmin => true)
```

Comment: Thanku for your response. So, I just needed to use current_admin... nothing else was needed to make it done. What would you suggest that shall I merge both tables? I made user and admin seperateyly thinking that users will increase anyhow, so searching the admin id from an increasing users table is not better in comparision to making a different admin model. What should I do? Will it create any problem in future?

Comment: _Technically_ storing administrative and standard users in two different tables could yield _slightly_ faster execution times, but it will most likely be negligible. I've added an explanation to my answer, outlining both this and an example. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation :) I will also keep a single table of users with an admin attribute :) :)